# Spring transfer SecurityContext for Integration testing

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

i want to test my REST Endpoints. In my REST methods are some filters based on the SecurityContext. When i set the SecurityContext in my test classes and call the rest methods, the SecurityContext is deleted. Only when i create the SecurityContext in my REST methods it has an effect. 
Is there a possibility how to transfer the context?

```
SecurityContext securityContext = new SecurityContextImpl();
    securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
    // is here User ...
    .mockMvc.perform(get("/test"...)
```

RestController:

```
public ResponseEntity<...> getTest(){
 // is now anonymus
 SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
}
```

thank you

Comment: See the answer by Rob Winch: [Run unit tests on controllers that require authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704428/)

Comment: You should (almost) never call `SecurityContextHolder` directly in your code. Instead you should just include a parameter of type `Authentication` in your controller method, and Spring will inject it (like it does with `HttpServletRequest/Response`, `Session`, `Model`, and a number of other types)

Answer (score 0):

You can set an authentication that is re-used for all tests in the same test class using `defaultRequest` method:

```java
@BeforeClass
public void setUp()
{
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).defaultRequest(get("/").with(authentication(authentication))).apply(springSecurity()).build();
}
```

The static imports you need are:

```
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.authentication;
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.springSecurity;
```